# Is there a way to hide the Messaging Tray in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, customization, messaging-tray

I find the Messaging Tray (the bottom bar) in GNOME Shell rather inconvenient. I'm looking for a way to disable it. KRSNA 2 ZED seems to have written [an extension](http://k2z.com/?p=110) for doing just that, but I don't know how to install it. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just managed to hide the messaging tray. Here are the steps I followed:

```
wget http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gn/gnome-shell-extension-remove-bottom-bar/gnome-shell-extension-remove-bottom-bar.tar.gz
tar -zxf gnome-shell-extension-remove-bottom-bar.tar.gz
cd gnome-shell-extension-remove-bottom-bar/
mkdir -p .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_bottom_bar@k2z.com
cp extension.js .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_bottom_bar@k2z.com/
cp metadata.json .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_bottom_bar@k2z.com/
```

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter <kbd>r</kbd>. After that, open [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool) [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool] and turn on the extension 'Remove bottom bar extension'.

[image]

---

There is an [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/238/disable-message-corner/) in the official GNOME extension website that lets you disable the messaging tray. You only have to download it from the site and turn it on in the gnome-tweak-tool to disable the corner.

Answer (score 1):

[Download the tar file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/removebottombar/files/gnome-shell-extension-remove-bottom-bar-3.2-1.src.tar.gz/download) and untar the file. It holds 3 files...

`extension.js`,
`metadata.json`,
`PKGBUILD`.

According to [Gnome Shell extensions](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions) you need to put these files in 1 of the following directories:

> Extension installation locations
>
> Extensions can be installed per-user in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, or systemwide in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `/usr/local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Thanks, but doing that didn't help. The extension doesn't pop up in `gnome-tweak-tool` either.

Answer (score 0):

check the metadata.json has the correct shell version as your gnome-shell and then logout should show up! if not then alt-f2 and type lg to see any errors.

gernerally when i install a new extension i change the shell version list to this

"shell-version": [ "3.2.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.3.3", "3.3.4", "3.4" ],

makes it easier if there is an update :-)

Answer (score 0):

to disable functionality without having to add an extension is:
`sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell-js/ui/messageTray.js`
find the line that says:`this._traySummoned = false;` and change the value to true (the line was 2198 on my version)