# In the Gnome Shell extension Icon Manager, how do I move the "Removable Devices" from the tray to the top panel?

Tags: gnome, configuration, extension, notification-area

In other words, what icon name do I have to put in dconf-editor/org/gnome/shell/extensions/icon-manager -> top-bar to get rid of the Removable Devices (and Ubuntu One) from sys tray?

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly try this GNOME extension:

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7/removable-drive-menu/

This extension adds a "status menu for accessing and unmounting removable devices."

[image]

This extension does not remove the removable devices from the messaging tray. You might want to try and hide the messaging tray to partially achieve the result you are looking for.

- [Is there a way to hide the Messaging Tray in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97046/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-messaging-tray-in-gnome-shell)

Answer (score 0):

This is a twofold answer:

1. removing the icon in the tray;
2. adding the icon in the panel.

---

### 1. Removing the icon in the tray

This seems to be a development issue regarding Gnome-Shell usage on Ubuntu. A similar case is the redundant keyboard-layout icon, which appears both in the tray and panel. [I reported the bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=669161) to Gnome, who explained:

> Ubuntu has patched gnome-settings-daemon to use libappindicator, which
>   falls back to legacy status icons if the required DBus daemon is not
>   running. This is the case when running GNOME Shell, which does not
>   support app indicators (the "indicator" in the top bar is build into
>   the shell), so the patched g-s-d falls back to a legacy icon which is
>   shown in the message tray

So regarding removal of the tray icon, I am not sure there is an easy answer (it might be a bug or development goal for Ubuntu instead), but someone may surely be able to provide a hack.

### 2. Adding the icon in the panel

To add the removable device icon in the panel, you need the [Removable Drive Menu extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7/removable-drive-menu/).

Comment: This answer doesn't really solve the problem. Feel free to edit and complement it if necessary.