# Gnome how to disable bottom panel

Tags: gnome, 15.04

I'd like to disable the bottom Gnome panel:

[image]

Comment: That thing at the bottom of the screen? I've never seen that before in GNOME.

Comment: Yes. If it isn't gnome, what could it be? It's reacting to the mouse touching the bottom.

Comment: It has a Dropbox button on it, so it could be that, but I think it's a Firefox plugin. Does it appear anywhere else?

Comment: You should also try right-clicking it to see if it shows the same right-click menu as the top panel.

Comment: It's also there if I close firefox. And it has a similar menu as Gnome.

Comment: Maybe it is a panel then. Open the menu and take a screenshot. Edit it into your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hide the Messaging Tray in GNOME Shell?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97046/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-messaging-tray-in-gnome-shell)

Comment: Can't take screenshots of the menu, only the bar. I tried the Gnome extension, it so far didn't work.